# Adding an event handler to a MenuItem within a ContextMenu within a ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `TreeView`, with a `ResourceDictionary`, containing a `ContextMenu`, with (currently) a single `MenuItem`.  (I will be adding more `MenuItem` later.)

I am trying to add an event to this via C# code-behind.  I know it's a bit odd to want to do this via code-behind rather than just specifying it in the XAML, but that is what I need to do for other requirements.

So, my hierarchy is:

- `Window` (no name/key)
- `Grid` (no name/key)
- `TreeView` (named treeView)
- `ContextMenu` (keyed allRequirementGroupsMenu)
- `MenuItem`

So, now I go to the code-behind, and I can navigate through this hierarchy, and I can add the event handler.

**Is there a better way to do this, via code-behind?**

---

**Code-Behind**

```
var contextmenu = treeView.TryFindResource("allRequirementGroupsMenu") as ContextMenu;
var mnu_create_reqgrp = contextmenu.Items.OfType<MenuItem>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(item => 
                            item.Name == "mnuItem_CreateRequirementGroup");
if(mnu_create_reqgrp != null)
    mnu_create_reqgrp.Click += RequirementGroup_Create_Click;
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1600">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="treeView">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <ContextMenu x:Key="allRequirementGroupsMenu" 
                                 StaysOpen="True">
                        <MenuItem Header="Create Requirement Group"  
                                  Name="mnuItem_CreateRequirementGroup" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Vendors" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Vendors}" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Checklists" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Checklists}" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Requirement Groups" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding RequirementGroups}" 
                          ContextMenu="{StaticResource allRequirementGroupsMenu}" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Ungrouped Items" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding UngroupedItems}" />
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why do you need a "better" way? Please describe what do you mean by "better". Anyway, you'd better use XAML data templates and event setters rather than code-behind.

Comment: Why are you modifying a local resource instead of hooking up the event handlers directly in your XAML markup?

Comment: @mm8 Eventually, I will be using this XAML in a Powershell script - I won't be using C#.  I haven't found an easy way to use C# code behind and XAML in Powershell.  I can use XAML, and I can use C# code... but I haven't found a way to link them together yet, so no way to link the method in the code-behind in XAML.  So, if I can do it in code-behind, then I can just convert the C# code to PowerShell and be done.

Comment: @dymanoid I am not sure exactly what better way exists.  It just seems a bit clunky for me.  I know that doing it XAML is preferred, but as per my other comment above, that won't work for me... unless you can help me to use PowerShell code-behind in XAML?